# How to disable warnings in NetBeans output window?

Tags: netbeans, warnings

Is it possible to disable WARNINGS (text in red) for the Output window, and only allow it to report errors?

[image]

I try a bit with the settings, and according to other posts I set Quiet for the Ant, and option -q for Maven, but it has no effect whatsoever.

[image]

[image]

So can anyone tell if it can be done at all, and if so, how, please?

Comment: This is nothing to do with NetBeans or Maven, and you would face the same issue with any IDE. Assuming that the application is writing those messages through a logger, you _might_ be able to configure the logger before running the application (e.g. By editing some properties file to specify the logging level). If the warnings become really bothersome an alternative approach would be to copy the entire content of the Output window into a text editor, then delete all the `WARNING:` lines before reviewing the output. Regardless, there's nothing you do within NetBeans to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see the warnings are generated by the program you execute (or maybe by a library used by your program).

Ant or Maven are build tools to generate your program, that's why changing their verbosity level won't impact the program output.

You should check if your program accepts some command-line options, there might be one to adjust the verbosity level.

EDIT: just had a look at "aparapi", I see that it's a library, so you should check the library API if you can configure the verbosity level, or if you can redirect log messages to a file.

Comment: Ah, so in another words: it cannot be set universally - I would have to check with every single program I am running inside NeBeans, unfortunately...which is no-go for me (I will have to live with it), but thanks for explanation

Comment: Yes, but this has nothing to do with Netbeans, it will be the same with whatever IDE you choose.